# How do I only allow crawlers to visit a part of the site?

Tags: php, web-crawler, robots.txt

I've got an ajax rich website which has extensive _escaped_fragment_ portions for Ajax indexing. While all my _escaped_fragment_ urls do 301 redirects to a special module which then outputs the HTML snapshots the crawlers need (i.e. `mysite.com/#!/content` redirects to `mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/content` which in turn 301s to `mysite.com/raw/content`), I'm somewhat afraid of users stumbling on those "raw" URLs themselves and making them appear in search engines.

In PHP, how do I make sure only robots can access this part of the website? (much like StackOverflow disallows its sitemap to normal users, and only lets robots access it)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not reliably.

`robots.txt` *asks* spiders to keep out of parts of a site, but there is no equivalent for regular user agents.

The closest you could come would be to try to keep a whitelist of acceptable ip addresses or user agents and serve different content based on that … but that risks false positives.

Personally, I'd stop catering for old-IE, scrap the `#!` URIs and the `escaped_fragment` hack, switch to using [`pushState` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), and have the server build the initial view for any given page.

Comment: I'm afraid the project's requirement is old-IE compatibility. Is there a list or wildcard of non-robot user agents I should ban on the PHP side in order to accomplish the solution you propose? I wouldn't be too restrictive - of course someone can spoof a UA, but I would like to do my best to keep the "raw" urls out of search engines.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll be taking a look at it in the coming days: http://phpmaster.com/server-side-device-detection-with-browscap/